# Git cli: get user info from username

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is there a way to get the name of the user, given only their username?

Something like this output `git show <username>` (I know this doesn't work)

```
username: username
name: First Last
email: email@address
```

I know I can do this with a GitHub api call, but would prefer to keep it within the CLI.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

*Git itself* (the command line client, i.e. the ["stupid content tracker"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git)) has no notion of user names, only GitHub does. In other words: there is no mapping of GitHub usernames to author/committer names and e-mails stored in a Git repository.

When creating a commit with Git it uses the configuration values of `user.name` (the real name) and `user.email` (email address). Those config values can be overridden on the console by setting and exporting the environment variables `GIT_{COMMITTER,AUTHOR}_{NAME,EMAIL}`.

Git doesn't know anything about GitHub's users, because GitHub is not part of Git. So you're only left with an API call to GitHub (I guess you could do that from the command line with a little scripting and make that a [Git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).)

Comment: Come on. How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051281/248616 `git config --list 
`

Comment: @NamGVU what do you mean? The OP was asking how to map _GitHub_ usernames to full names and emails of committers. And that is not possible. Using `git config --list` (or rather `git config user.name`) will only show _your_ currently configured author/committer name. It will not display any other user names or email addresses. It's interesting that so many answers which do _not_ answer get so many upvotes. Useful for a different usecase? Definitely. Answering the question? No.

Comment: this is the correct answer. The correct way to get the username is to query the hosting service (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc).

Answer (score 153):

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

I believe these are the commands you are looking for.

[Here is where I found them](http://alvinalexander.com/git/git-show-change-username-email-address)

Answer (score 79):

`git config --list` 
 `git config -l`
 will display your username and email together, along with other info

Answer (score 31):

Try this

```
git config user.name
```

git config command stores and gives all the information.

```
git config -l
```

This commands gives you all the required info that you want.

You can change the information using

```
git config --global user.name "<Your-name>"
```

Similarly you can change many info shown to you using `-l` option.

Answer (score 14):

While its true that git commits don't have a specific field called "username", a git repo does have users, and the users do have names.  ;)  If what you want is the github username, then knittl's answer is right.  But since your question asked about git cli and not github, here's how you get a git user's email address using the command line:

To see a list of all users in a git repo using the git cli:

```
git log --format="%an %ae" | sort | uniq
```

To search for a specific user by name, e.g., "John":

```
git log --format="%an %ae" | sort | uniq | grep -i john
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this to see the logged in user (the actual git account):

```
git config credential.username
```

And as other answers the user email and user name (this is differenct from user credentials):

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

To see the list of all configs:

```
git config --list
```

Comment: `git config credential.username` works depending on how you logged in. If the user set up SSH remotes, this won't be set.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this to get infos like:

- username: `git config --get user.name`
- user email: `git config --get user.email`

There's nothing like "first name" and "last name" for the user.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using GitHub CLI (because `git` is already installed):

```
grep "user:" ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml
```

---

2022: Unless you manually set a token by hand, you need to use `gh` cli with `git` in order to be able to `git push` to your own GitHub repos. `gh` cli can be used to automatically set token credential use, as opposed to *onetime* (per login), or *everytime* (per action).

https://github.com/cli/cli

https://cli.github.com

Comment: I have multiple hosts configured in gh, so I can first grep for the line after `github.com:` then find the user: `grep 'github.com:' ~/.config/gh/hosts.yml -A 1 | grep "user:"`

Comment: You might prefer using: `gh api user --jq .name` (note: hosts.yml is written only if the user is already logged)

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but since it's still the first hit on Google search, I'll add my two cents. Most answers are technically not correct. As [@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552869/226819) indicated: to get the username, you'll have to query the service hosting your code, as git itself has no notion of users. You can configure variables like the `user.name`, but this can be anything and is not necessarily the user creating the commit.

For Github, a way to get the actual username is through their CLI tool [gh](https://github.com/cli/cli). Once downloaded and authenticated, you can issue the following to get the username (using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to retrieve the name):

`gh api 'https://api.github.com/user' | jq .login`

Answer (score 1):

Add my two cents, if you're using windows commnad line:

`git config --list | findstr user.name` will give username directly.

The `findstr` here is quite similar to `grep` in linux.

Answer (score 1):

its So Simple You Just Copy and Past

**For List Of All Config** :- `git config --list`

**and Also You Can Try** :- `git config -l`

if you need to perticular Than You Can Use

**user name** :- `git config user.name`

**user email** :- `git config user.email`

If you need To add Config Than

**user name** :- `git config user.name "name of user"`

**user email** :- `git config user.email "email of user"`

Hope its HelpFull,
Thank You