# How to list all contributors user.name of a repository from windows commandline

Tags: git

As the title, I want to get all contributors' `user.name` from windows command line using `git` command.

There are many similar solutions like [List all developers on project in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597410/list-all-developers-on-project-in-git)

However, the user name listed is not actually `user.name`, it's in the format as FirstName, LastName.

[image]

As the picture, what I want is "yyx990803" but not "Evan You".
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please distinguish between Git and GitHub. They are not the same thing. What those commands are showing _is_ `user.name` as it existed for that user at the time they made that commit. If you want to extract the GitHub username from the Git revision history, you're out of luck: it isn't there, for the simple reason that a Git repo can exist independent of GitHub. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600040/get-github-username-from-commit-history

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reminder. Let me clarify whether I understand you correctly. The name "yyx990803" is only GitHub thing but not Git. The only user name in Git can be shown by method mentioned in below url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597410/list-all-developers-on-project-in-git ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the clarification. ^_^

Comment: If you want the GitHub user names, you can look into the GitHub APIs.